# Parse yaml list and save it to variables in python

Tags: python, yaml

I have yaml file, which I would like to iterate and save everything from the list as a new variable with the same name.

```
- app1:
   name: example1
   host: example1
   run: myscript1.sh
   tags: 
    - "user"  
    - "age"  
    - "gender"             
 
- app2:
   name: example2
   host: example4
   tags: 
    - "user"  
    - "age"  
    - "height"
```

Code:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    for key, value in data[i].items():
        print(value.get('tags'))
        for n in tags:
            print(n)
```

output:

```
['user', 'age', 'gender']
user
age
user
['user', 'age', 'height']
user
age
height
```

Would like in new iteration to save these values as variables,

```
user = 'user'
age = 'age'
height = 'height'
```

and in next iteration:

```
  user = 'user'
  age = 'age'
  gender = 'gender'
```

So I can pass these variables to some other stuff in the code.

**EDIT**

yaml variable (e.g. host) will be populated with the values from Elasticsearch. If we define in tags "age", I'll search Elasticsearch for "age" and grab value from document, so it becomes "age": "20". After that, this "age" tag will be called in sh script, something like:

```
for doc1 in resp['hits']['hits']:
            command = f"{value.get('run')} --age {age} #and other tags"
            p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite certain what you want, but I think you're after something like this:

```yaml
# test.yml
- app1:
   name: example1
   host: example1
   tags: 
    - "user"  
    - "age"  
    - "gender"             
 
- app2:
   name: example2
   host: example4
   tags: 
    - "user"  
    - "age"  
    - "height"
```

```py
import yaml
from pathlib import Path

with Path("test.yml").open() as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

out = []

for entry in data:
    app, *_ = entry.keys()
    tags = {k: k for k in entry[app]["tags"]}
    out.append(tags)

print(out)
```

You could easily save these by the app name instead, by making out a dict.

Note that I don't know *why* you are after redundant key/value pairs, and if `tags` is actually supposed to contain data (unlike in your example) you will have to do something like:

```py
tags = {k:v for k, v in entry[app]["tags"].items()}
```

Lastly you can of course dump back to yaml with `yaml.dump(out)`.

### ** Unpacking

It occurs to me you might want to *unpack* this dict into a function.  You can do so like this:

```py
def my_fn(user=None, age=None, gender=None, height=None):
    print("user", user, "age", age, "gender", gender, "height", height)

out = [{'user': 'user', 'age': 'age', 'gender': 'gender'},
 {'user': 'user', 'age': 'age', 'height': 'height'}]

for row in out:
    my_fn(**row)
```

Thus ** unpacks the dict into keyword arguments, which *might* be what you were looking for.  (At any rate it makes more sense to me than generating variables with programmatic names).  Note the `app, *_` which unpacked `entry.keys()` so we could get the first item without having to cast it to an indexable type.  `dict.keys()` isn't a generator, so you can't use `next(dict.keys())`.  This particular unpacking is a recent (and very useful) addition to python.

### EDIT: using these variables

> yaml variable (e.g. host) will be populated with the values from Elasticsearch. If we define in tags "age", I'll search Elasticsearch for "age" and grab value from document, so it becomes "age": "20".

Right.  So you want to see *what* entries are in `tags`, and then populate them with the right values.  So you want to do something like this:

```py
for entry in data:
    tags = {}
    app, *_ = entry.keys()
    for tag in in entry[app]["tags"]:
        val = get_tag_value_from_elasticsearch(tag)
        tags[tag] = val
```

> After that, this "age" tag will be called in sh script

So---still in the same loop for simplicity, but you can always append `tags` to a list and then iterate that list later:

```
    cmd = ["command"]
    for param, val in tags.items():
        cmd += [f"--{param}", str(val)]
    res = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)
    print(res.stdout)
```

Note a few things here: I've avoided the use of `.get()` to lookup a value in a dict when I can just use `[]` access; I've used `subprocess.run` instead of Popen (if you want to background you'll have to go back to Popen), and I've build the command up directly in a list, rather than building a string and splitting it.

At this point anything else you want to do with it is I think another question, so I'm going to leave this answer here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs, the thing is I need to do it is because based on parameters that are being defined in yaml, I'm doing a search request on elasticsearch, and I need to store these "particular" values as variables. E.g. I'll look for height and gender and then save these 2 -> afterwards I need to call some sh script with those parameters. Not sure If I made myself clear, will try to explain in next comment

Comment: Have a look at what I do in the last part (try running that).  I think you can get at the data you need.  But it would definitely help if you put an example of how you want to *use* this data in the question.  I *do* save the data in a variable---specifically in a dict, which can then be unpacked into a function when you call.

Comment: Thnx @2e0byo , I made edits, hope you understand now what I've been doing

Comment: Right, I've updated that answer (but it's so unweildy I'm going to leave it there).  Hopefully that gives you the tools to solve it :)

Comment: tnx, just getting NameError: name 'get_tag_value_from_elasticsearch' is not defined, i'm not sure what is it

Comment: well, yes, that's where you have to get the tag value from elasticsearch, however you were planning on doing that ;)  i.e. it's a placeholder fn

Comment: I’ve managed to get the values, but unfortunately they are not correctly passed to subprocess, maybe i need to check if my bash script is correct. Thank you